# How do I alternate table row colors in asp.net mvc using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Probably a dumb question but I'm new to MVC and jQuery. I want to alternate the row colors of my tables and I've decided that I'm going to use jQuery to do it. I know that I could write an extension method (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/07/aspnetmvc_cycle.aspx), etc but after reading SH's comment on the article at http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/03/code-based-repeater-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx I've picked jQuery as the solution I want to implement.

I want to implement the method described at http://www.packtpub.com/article/jquery-table-manipulation-part2 but I haven't figured out where to put the initial jQuery call (eg: $(document).ready(function() {...});

Like I said, I'm new to jQuery...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting a class on all the even rows of a table.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('tr:even').addClass('alt-row-class');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Then apply style to that class using standard css:

```
.alt-row-class { background-color: green; }
```

A commenter correctly points out that you might wish to play around with the selector (`tr:even`) to get the results you want relative to `tbody`, `thead` and `tfoot` elements.

Comment: I usually apply this to the tbody rows only, with separate classes for thead/tfoot.

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in my google search, but I haven't worked out where that jQuery code goes. My first thought was to add a script tag, but that failed miserably. Where do I include your snippet in my view?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, do I also need a script reference to jQuery?

Comment: Yes, you do.  Sorry for leaving it out.  I've added it.

Comment: language="text/javascript" makes it so that firefox and safari will not run the javascript. language="javascript" works though. You may be thinking of type="text/javascript" I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Be aware that if you use jQuery and the user has javascript turned off, your UI is not going to get styled the way you want.  You may want to consider doing the assignment of CSS classes for styling in the view code itself.

```
   @{ var alternating = false;
      foreach (var row in Model) {
          <tr class='@(alternating ? "alternating-row" : "normal-row")'>
          ...
          alternating = !alternating;
   }
```

Comment: <tr class="<%= alternating == true ? "alternating-row" : "normal-row" %>">

Comment: Never test if a boolean is `== true`, just test the boolean: `<tr class="<%= alternating ? "alternating-row" : "normal-row" %>">`

Comment: @Stephen P: I always test the boolean directly myself, but always thought it was a matter of preference. Why the 'never'?

Comment: @KTF: strictly speaking I guess it could be called a matter of preference (nothing bad will happen from it) but I find it *harder* to read, and a well-named boolean in a test can be so much clearer, e.g. `if (isAlternateRow)` over `if (alternateRow == true)`. Both that style and the ternary `isAlternateRow ? "this" : "that"` are idioms that I believe are a sign of a well-seasoned programmer.

Comment: @Stephen P: Gotcha. I agree; I'm the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the jQuery plugin [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html), it has a built-in "widget" for this called "zebra" (among all of its other functionality).