# MVC alternating color for table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a standard loop that lists a table of things. And I would like to do some sort  "i % 2", but I dont know how to get that "index"-value for each row in model.

```
    <% foreach (var item in Model.Users) { %>

    <tr>
        <td><%= item.Firstname %></td>
        <td><%= item.Surname %></td>
        <td><%= item.Email %></td>
        <td><%= item.Datecreated %></td>
    </tr>

<% } %>
```

how do I apply alternating color for table? either "class1" or "class2" for each "td"

Thanks in advance

/M

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663107/how-do-i-alternate-table-row-colors-in-asp-net-mvc-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% int i = 0; %>
<% foreach (var item in Model.Users) { i++; %>
```

then you just do your "i % 2" :)